# Spam Flag was Raised, Disputed, Question On Hold and Removed, All Within 1 Minute

Tags: support, flags, disputed-flags

This seems like a very odd set of circumstances to me.

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336900/how-this-site-look-good-or-bad) as spam shortly after it was posted. For those who can't see deleted questions, it was a link to a website asking people to rate it.

I checked my Flagged Posts and at first the flag was set and pending. In the next few seconds the question was put on hold and then deleted entirely, but my flag is disputed (see the screenshot below).

[image: Spam flag disputed]

Surely this can't be right. <s>If a 10k user deemed the flag invalid,</s> how did the question get deleted so quickly and therefore (I assume) was accepted by other users?

Comment: "10k user deemed the flag invalid" - they can't review those flags. Please **don't** confuse mods and 10k users.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That post is not at first glance clear and cut spam. It looks like a confused user asking for feedback.

Spam flags have very specific penalties for the posting account, and feed into the automated spam system. The network from which the account is posting may also be blacklisted. As such, moderators will decline spam flags on posts that do not qualify for this treatment.

In this case, the link points to a crummy classified ads site, personally I'd have thought it was spam too, but this close to the line you can expect some flags to be declined.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: The extended discussion in the comments has clouded what this answer is about. If you have a question about how we handle things as moderators, feel free to pose a meta question. If you are seeking clarification about *this answer*, please leave a comment.